# cucumber/runner/TimeServiceEventBus cucumber testng implementation

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I want to run cucumber using testng to get more control over my test. However I am getting this error while running it... how to fix this and get my test running... please advise... also unable to run extent report by using extentreportformatter stuck from everywhere.. please help to resolve this:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/runner/TimeServiceEventBus

    at com.syn.runner.FeatureRunnerTest.setUpClass(FeatureRunnerTest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:cucumber.runner.TimeServiceEventBus
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 26 more
```

Pom

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0

    <groupId>SynAutomationFramework</groupId>
    <artifactId>SynAutomationFramework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vimalselvam/cucumber-extentsreport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

runner class

```
    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
    import cucumber.api.testng.*;
    import org.testng.annotations.*;
    import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
    import cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;


    //@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

    @CucumberOptions(  monochrome = true,
        features = "src/test/resources/features/",
        glue = {"steps"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/reports/jsonreports.json" }
    )


    public class FeatureRunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{
     @AfterClass
    public static void afterSuite(){

        GenerateReport.generateReport();

        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "src\\target\\cucumber-html-reports\\overview-features.html";
        //String htmlpath = "<a href=" + path + " alt='Path of the Test Report1'>Path of the Test Report</a>";
        System.out.println(path);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

In combination with:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

All Cucumber dependencies should have the same version.

Also note that you are including more dependencies then strictly needed in your pom. If you are using `cucumber-java` you only need to add `cucumber-testng`. All other dependencies are transitive and will be loaded by maven.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError means that the class is present in the classpath at compile time, but that the class doesn't exist in the classpath at Runtime.

In your POM, let all your scopes default to compile (e.g. remove all the

```
<scope>...<scope/>
```

tags) and let us know if that fixes it.

Comment: thanks for looking into this... It did not solve the issue completely. I tried to run mvn test through bash shell again and I got the same error ..

Comment: so after removing the scope, I am able to run the runner file by right clicking on it using intellij without defining the main class in run/edit configuration / testng.

however issue exists when I try to run from bash shell using command line mvn test

Comment: Without an IDE, you have to set the classpath explicitly. See, for example [How to get the classpath](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206757845-Intellij14-How-to-get-the-classpath-of-the-current-project-) and [how to set the classpath](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/java-set-classpath-command-line-examples/).

Comment: Thanks ..but apologies as I am not able to use 
String fullClasspath = OrderEnumerator.orderEntries(module).recursively().getPathsList().getPathsString()

or code about it to get classpath.....it doenot accept OrderEnumerator, modules ect..

Comment: I used System.getProperty("java.class.path") to get the class path and got a string..it shows lot of jar files ..not sure if thats the right thing i am looking it

Comment: That is possibly correct.  What happens if you print this string? String fullClasspath = OrderEnumerator.orderEntries(module).recursively().getPathsList().getPathsString()

Comment: thanks a ton for your help...looks like I had spent lot of time to get this resolved.. there is not much documentation to resolve this error...I am no longer using TestNg  so to get rid of it..I removed AbstractTestNGCucumberTests and started using JUnit annotations....it served my purpose.thanks